# ISO C99 intypes.h: printf does not print hex value for a uint64_t

Tags: c

My code is this (main.c):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 uint64_t n;

 n = UINT64_MAX;

 printf("%" PRIX64 " %" PRIu64 "\n", n, n);

 return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is this:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18446744073709551615
```

But I am looking for this:

```
10000000000000000 18446744073709551615
```

I am using GCC (gcc -std=c99 main.c):
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Looking for an answer in google gave me this:
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/565055-convert-64-integer-hex-octet-string

Now, I am lost. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the value of `UINT64_MAX` should be `0xffffffffffffffff` as that is the value of 64-bits all set. I don't understand why you expect `0x10000000000000000` (which requires **65-bits to represent**).

Also `18446744073709551615` in decimal is equal to `0xffffffffffffffff`, so printf is doing the right thing.

Comment: I was expecting 0x10000000000000000 because that's what one calculator on the internet converted. Also, the gcalctool (the calculator in ubuntu 10.10) simply does not display anything, it stops converting values at 4294967295. So, I thought the one on the web was right.

Comment: `2^64 == 0x10000000000000000`. However, a 64-bit variable can only represent `0` through `(2^64)-1`.

Comment: You also may want to try kcalc, it correctly supports 64-bit values.

Comment: Even at first glance, 18446744073709551615 is an odd number, so when expressed as a hexadecimal it must still end with an odd digit (one of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, b, d, f).

Comment: gcalctool also supports 64-bit values, I just made some sloppy moves there. Thanks again all for the observations.